# how disk became suddenly write protected in spite configuration is read/write

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, mount, redhat-enterprise-linux

we have linux redhat 7 machine
and the filesystem for device - /dev/sdc is ext4
the HW is new HW and new disks

when we perform:

```
mount -o rw,remount /grop/sdc
```

we get write protected error

like:

```
/dev/sdc read-write, is write-protected
```

in spite the /etc/fstab allow read and write and all sub folder under /grop/sdc have full write/read permissions !

```
/dev/sdc /grop/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

then we do

```
umount -l  /grop/sdc
```

and from `df -h`, we see that the disk is currently not mounted

then we perform

```
 mount /grop/sdc
```

but we get busy   -:( -:(

so we do not have a choice and we performe a reboot

and from history we do not see that someone limited the disk for read only by mount

this is very strange, how the disk device became write protected?

in order to solve this we perform a full reboot

and now the disk is **write/read** as it should be

what happens here,

after reboot we check the dmesg and we see the following:

```
 EXT4-fs warning (device sdc): ext4_clear_journal_err:4698: Marking fs in need of filesystem check.
 EXT4-fs (sdc): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
 EXT4-fs (sdc): recovery complete
```

**can we say that during boot - e2fsck was performed ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can say that during boot an fsck was performed.

For some reason your disk got corrupted, so the IS refused to mount it as RW because that would allow errors to compound.  On startup Linux saw the disk was "dirty" and did an fsck to clean it prior to mounting it.

If the problem occurs again You can fix it by doing an fsck prior to mounting - but you should really discover the cause of the corruption and fix that.